# Break Wordpress post loop and continue it

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, indexing

I have a Wordpress blog that shows the last 10 posts on the main page:

```
 <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                            <?php

                                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                            ?>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I want to break the loop after 5 posts, put another code (a widget that I wrote), then continue the loop and display the rest of the posts, so my main page will be like: 
**5 Recent posts -> widget -> the next 5 posts.** 
I manged to display the recent 5 posts, but can't display the 5 next posts.
Anyone have an idea? :)

Comment: I would do this with javascript. Much easier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include your widget after the 5th post has been shown; no need to break up the loop. Use a counter and check when the 5th post is displayed.

Change this:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

To:

```
<?php $count = 1;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php 
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

    if ( 5 === $count ) {

        // code to display beneath 5th post.

    }

    $count++; ?>  

<?php endwhile; ?>
```